# FilterPane Grails Plugin: how to hide the combo box

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm learning how to use the next search plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/filterpane

I'm executing the example project of the plugin: https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-filterpane-demo/

I want to hide the combo box:

[image: default combo box screenshot]

For example, let say we want to filter as follow:

[image]

Is it possible with this plugin? Do you recommend to use another one? Do you recommend to do it manually without any plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to override filterpane template.

- Create file grails-app/views/_filterpane/_filterpaneProperty.gsp
- Insert [original source](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-filterpane/blob/master/grails-app/views/_filterpane/_filterpaneProperty.gsp).
- Change select tag with a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think what you say would work, but I cannot try it. I did this question six months ago. I decided to program the filter - search manually. As I think this solution is correct, I'm going to mark it as correct for future searches.